# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime on Win 10 64

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to install TensorFlow as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) on my Windows 10 (x64) machine.

First I installed CUDA. My GPU (GTX 660ti, Compute Capability 3.0) is supported.
Versions: Toolkit 9.0 (accidently installed 9.1 aswell beforehand), cuDNN v7.0.5 for CUDA 9.0

Then I installed Tensorflow using native pip3. Python-Version: 3.6.4

When I'm just importing the tensorflow package I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have the following System environment variables set:

```
CUDA_PATH - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0
CUDA_PATH_V9_0 - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0
CUDA_PATH_V9_1 - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1
Path - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\libnvvp;
```

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.24215 installed. MSVCP140.dll is in my System32 folder.

What I also tried:

- Using Python version 3.6.2 (What i currently have)
- Installing via anaconda
- Using pip instead of pip3
- Upgrading pip3, pip
- Reinstalling
- Using tensorflow version from uci repository

Using alternative numpy, scipy, tensorflow versions from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow), I got a slightly different stacktrace:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 35, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 35, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the version from the uci repository for 64 bit Windows binaries, try removing the version you have again and then download and pip installing the version from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error again ...

Comment: hmm, did you try downloading and installing numpy from the same site and download the suggested  Visual C++ 2017? Instructions are at the top the page.

Comment: add the scipy version on there to that ^ list as well

Comment: I reinstalled Visual C++ 2017, then removed numpy, scipy, protobuf, tensorflow and installed numpy, scipy, protobuf and tensorflow again using the files from uci repo. I'm basically getting the same error, but now it's slightly different... (See above)