# tensorflow-gpu in win10: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-10, cudnn

I have a problem when installing tensorflow-gpu in win10 (64 bits), it is my configuration:

- Python 3.6.8 (64 bits)
- Tensorflow 1.12 (pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu)
- CUDA 9.1  (cuda_9.1.85_win10.exe)
- cudNN 7  (cudnn-9.1-windows10-x64-v7)
- GTX 965M

I also set the Environment variables:

[CUDA_PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFywr.png)

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfb5p.png)

I copied the cudNN files in the NVDIA Toolkit folder:

[Copied files:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQD78.png)

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributalbe in my laptop

My error is similar to this one: [Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime on Win 10 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781077/failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime-on-win-10-64)

This is my error:

```
    import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Josema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Any ideas?? I do not see that I did wrong

Answer (score 2):

These things occur due to not fulfilling of all the dependencies which are needed by tensorflow. Instead of using pip, install tensorflow by using anaconda

Comment: you are right! I think the cause was that the day I wanted to install it my internet was slow so some dependencies were not installed well. What I did I created a virtual env and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I wouldn't use conda to install tensorflow as it installs a lot of other stuff you may not need. Have you tried to downgrade tensorflow to, for example, version 1.14.0? It worked for me.